# Boot from one of two USB drives

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot

I am using Windows 10 with a USB thumb drive set as ReadyBoost. I wanted to boot the machine to Ubuntu using a USB Thumb drive. But whenever I try booting from the USB, it says OS not found. This happens when I have the Ready Boost drive pugged in.

If I remove the ready boost drive, things work fine, but I lose the readyboost when I boot normally to Windows.

Any way out? I do not want to install Linux on the hard drive asI have limited space on the hard drive.

Comment: Ensure your bootable USB device has higher priority in your BIOS's boot order than the ReadyBoost one.

Comment: I am not sure how I can put one USB drive at a higher priority than the other. The boot priority list down the classes/types of device like Hard Disk, CD-ROM, USB etc. But does not provide USB1, USB2 etc. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>F12</kbd> for bootmenu and select the device you want to boot from.

<kbd>F12</kbd> is the most widely used for entering bootmenu, but depending on how old your computer/laptop is or who is the vendor, it could be any function key between the <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>. Some notebooks have dedicated button next to power button that will allow you to access BIOS menu and select the bootmenu (like IBM/Lenovo). For notebooks/netbooks keep in mind that depending on the keyboard configuration, you will be required to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: @xypha not sure what you are trying to ask me and about purpose and what steps you are talking about? Bootmenu will list the available bootable devices and all you have to do is to select the one you want to boot from (using the arrow keys on your keyboard :) ) and press Enter

Comment: I am not sure how I can put one USB drive at a higher priority than the other. The boot priority list down the classes/types of device like Hard Disk, CD-ROM, USB etc. But does not provide USB1, USB2 etc. Or am I missing something? Pressing F12 I cannot select a particular USB drive.

Comment: A device/partition without \EFI folder (and not formatted as FAT/32) will not show as EFI boot device.

Comment: But he wrote that after removing the  Ready Boost drive, he cam boot without issue